# How to modify a sublime-syntax file to include following lines in sytnax coloring?

Tags: syntax, yaml, sublimetext3, editor

I'm trying to color a log file, and a simple syntax definition:

```
%YAML 1.2
---
name: Fluxus Log Syntax
file_extensions:
  - log
scope: source.customlog
contexts:
  main:
    - match: '.*\|Debug\|.*$'
      scope: debug.line.log
    - match: '.*\|Info\|.*$'
      scope: info.line.log
    - match: '.*\|Warning\|.*$'
      scope: warning.line.log
    - match: '.*\|Error\|.*$'
      scope: error.line.log
```

is close, however, it doesn't, for example, color the following lines of error traces in red:

[image: syntax highlighting]

Any ideas on how to fix simply? I've tried `meta_context` and `pop`ing and haven't had luck...